# How to search for files and attach them to a Email

Tags: vb.net, email

I have an CheckedListbox (imported from mysql Database) that lists all my folders where my files are saved. And what I need to do is for every checked item in the CheckListbox, to search the folder and then attach the file from that folder to a Mail.

What I have done is to create an Email and to send it with only one attachment.
Just with the: "e_mail. Attachments. Add". The Mail will be generated and that found file will be attached and send.

But when I do that in a FOR EACH LOOP then no file will be selected and added to my Mail. The Mail will be generated and send without any errors, but there are no attached files.

```
 Private Sub SendMail()
    Dim Smtp_Server As New SmtpClient
    Dim e_mail As New MailMessage()
    Smtp_Server.UseDefaultCredentials = False
    Smtp_Server.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("MAIL", "PASS")
    Smtp_Server.Port = 587
    Smtp_Server.EnableSsl = True
    Smtp_Server.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    Smtp_Server.Host = "HOST"
    If MonthTextBox.Text = "" Or MonthTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Silver Then
        MsgBox("Input month please", Title:="MO Text Box")
    Else
        Dim MOTextValue As String = MonthTextBox.Text
        Dim nowYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year

        For Each itemchecked As DataRowView In CheckedListBoxWO.CheckedItems
            Dim File_path As String = "C:\Test\" & itemchecked.Item(1) & "\" & nowYear & "\" & MOTextValue & "\"
            Dim File_Name As String = Dir("C:\Test\" & itemchecked.Item(1) & "\" & nowYear & "\" & MOTextValue & "\File " & MOTextValue & "*.xlsx")
            Dim attachmentFile As Net.Mail.Attachment = New Net.Mail.Attachment(File_path & File_Name)
            e_mail.Attachments.Add(attachmentFile)
        Next

        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        sb.AppendLine("Hello,<br />")
        sb.AppendLine("<br />")            
        sb.AppendLine("Test Attachment,<br />")           
        sb.AppendLine("<br />")
        sb.AppendLine("------------------------------------------<br />")            
        e_mail.From = New MailAddress("MY MAIL")
        e_mail.To.Add("EMAIL")
        e_mail.Subject = ("TESTFILE - " & MOTextValue & "")
        e_mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        e_mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        e_mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
        e_mail.Body = sb.ToString()
        e_mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        Smtp_Server.Send(e_mail)
    End If
    MsgBox("Mails was sent", Title:="Mail")
End Sub
```

Like I told with this code the Mail will be created and send, but there is no Attachment file in it.
If I do it without the "FOR EACH"... loop, then one File will be added without a problem. But I need to add more files, actually for every checked Item in the CheckedListBox my program should search that folder and if there is a file than attach it in the Mail, and look in the other folder and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Your adding attachments then newing up your `e_mail` object again, this will wipe your existing data, try removing the indicated line below:

```
sb.AppendLine("<br />")
sb.AppendLine("------------------------------------------<br />") 

e_mail = New MailMessage()     <--- remove this line

e_mail.From = New MailAddress("MY MAIL")
e_mail.To.Add("EMAIL")
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working, I mean the Mail is bean created and send, but with no attached files :-/

Comment: So why are you newing it up twice? Given the code you provided, there is absolutely no way there could be attached files. Update your code shown.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I have tried to remove that line and it is still the same. A Mail is created and send but without attachments.

Comment: I have changed the code above so that it is clear. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually working, my problem was that the reference to this CheckListBox was incorrect, I have multiple CheckListBoxes, and that one in the Code was not the one I was actually using... But looking it from the bright side, THE CODE IS WORKING :)